# Does height CSS attribute (100%, 100vh) have some meaning for <html> or <body> tags?

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with html/body/div nested structures to achieve complex layout in which browser scrollbars are prevented and only inner components (e.g. datagrids) can have some inner scrollbars. For this I have question - **does height CSS attribute have some meaning for html and body tags?** I am not talking about HTML height attribute (there is no such HTML attribute for html or body), but I mean CSS style attribute.

Comment: html and body tag are like any other tags, so the height apply to them like on the other.

Comment: Of course it does. But since the `html` element represents the viewport, it has a slightly different effect on that one.

Comment: @04FS html doesn't represent the viewport. Both are two different elements

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has meaning for them. `<html>` and `<body>` are valid html elements and they can be styled by your CSS. The body and html element do not necessarily start at 100% height although some browsers might add some CSS to the elements to start with.

All DOM elements can be styled although some may behave differently.